# Printing in a selected line of a created .rtf File

Tags: vba, excel

I want to select the .rtf File, that I created automatically, with filedialog.

My Code for the creation of the file looks as follows:

```
TargetData = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="AVL (*.rtf), *.rtf", InitialFileName:="AVL.rtf")
```

To call It I would take something like:

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
fd.Select.Targetdata
```

How would you do this?

Best regards

Comment: You title doesn't seem to match your question. Are you looking to open a file that the user selects?

Comment: Hello Harassed, my intention was to load the rtf file, that I created. Afterwards I want to use the Data, that was put into the file and sort it with another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dim s As String
 Dim wb As Workbook
 s = Application.GetOpenFilename("*.rtf,*.rtf", , "Select File Name")
 If Not s = "False" Then
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(s)
 End If
```

at the end of this fragment wb is either Nothing or a pointer to the open rtf file.

Comment: Hello Harassed, thanks for your answer! I will try that one and give you feedback soon.